# Using environment variables with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm building a group of projects from the SVN. There is a possibility of changing the SVN location time to time.  As there are bunch of projects I hope to give the repository url with a environment variable so i can change all the url's easily. Any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 4):

In Subversion Source Code Management, you can use variable in the **Repository URL**, simply type:
`http://my.svn.com/path/to/${VARIABLE}`

`${VARIABLE}` is a job parameters that is defined earlier. Never heard of anyone wanting to use actual environment variables for this, but you can try with the same syntax.

By default, it will give you a red warning that this is not a valid URL. You can disable this warning by going to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and look for **Validate repository URLs up to the first variable name**. Put a checkmark there and save.

Comment: I was not able to do this. It was not resolving the ${VARIABLE}